# Second OS Concerns

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multi-boot

I have two Operating systems installed in my computer, Windows 7 and Windows 10. The second OS that was installed in my computer is Windows 10 but most of my important programs were installed using Windows 7 and was installed in its partition.

Now my problem is when I search for those for those programs using my Windows 10, it does not show up. Programs like Microsoft Office, Web browsers, DevC, Photoshop and more.

Is it possible to make those programs visible to Windows 10? If it is, how do I make it visible? :)

Comment: You could with very little effort sync the application data for more of those applications between the two installations.  They would still have to be installed on each instance of Windows though.

Answer (score 1):

No,

Everything installed as a program under windows 7, will have been configured for windows 7 as well, you can't simply 'share' the program between any two O/S's without a lot of work.

However, if you mounted your windows 7 partition under windows 10, you could potentinally access your personal files at least.

Comment: May I know what you mean about mounting my windows 7 partition under windows 10?